# Android:Run Time Removal of Sim Card for HTC One V

Tags: android

I want a notification at run time removal of sim card from android phone .

My Application is running on GingerBread while it is not running on HTC One V which runs on ICS and above.
Here is my code :

1)  Receiver Class

```
package com.TestIt;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SimEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent systemIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent=new Intent(context, SimService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}

}
```

2)Service Class

```
package com.TestIt;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimService extends Service {
TelephonyManager tele;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Kanishk", "In Service OnCreate");


    int simState = tele.getSimState();
    switch (simState)
    {
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
        Log.d("kanishk", "onCreate1");
        TestItActivity.simState(this);
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
        Log.d("kanishk", "onCreate2");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Now Sim is ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        Log.d("kanishk", "onCreate3");
        Toast.makeText(this, "not Known", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

3)Activity
    package com.TestIt;

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestItActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private  static final String tag = "Activity";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(tag, "OnCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public static void simState()
{
    Log.d(tag, "Sim State");
}
}
```

4)Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.systemEvent"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SystemEventActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BroadCastReceiverS"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MyService" >
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: it is not at all running on HTC One V running on ICS

Comment: What do you mean by not running? Does it force close? Does it work on other Android versions?

Comment: yes it runs on Samsung Galaxy which has GingerBread.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 3.1, all applications are set to **STOPPED STATE** when installed. The  application is taken out of the **STOPPED STATE** when the user runs the application for the first time. An application is also put back in the **STOPPED STATE** when the user uses the application manager to manually stop it.

Since your application contains only a `Service` component and a `BroadcastReceiver` component, it is obviously never explicitly started by the user (there is no `Activity` for the user to start). Therefore, your application is never taken out of the **STOPPED STATE**.

Your `BroadcastReceiver` will never be run because the system does not send broadcast `Intent`s to applications in the **STOPPED STATE**.

Read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html). Look at the section *"Launch controls on stopped applications"*. Note particularly this quote:

> Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all
>   broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background
>   services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of
>   stoppped applications. A background service or application can
>   override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
>   flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped
>   applications.
>
> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but
>   are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user
>   (in Manage Applications).

Comment: public class AutoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i=new Intent(context, MyService.class);
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    context.startService(i);
    }
}I have added a flag still this code is not running . Sir if possibe please improve my code or suggest me a running code.

Comment: Adding `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` in this situation has no effect. For the flag to be useful it needs to be added to the broadcast `Intent` when the broadcast `Intent` is sent. Since you aren't sending the broadcast `Intent` (you are only listening for it), there isn't anything you can do. If your application is in the **STOPPED STATE** the only way to get it out of the **STOPPED STATE** is to have the user run it again manually.

Comment: Sir i have make some changes still my code is not running saying application is not installed.while it showing in manage apps as well in the gridview.plz help me

Comment: Post the logcat and post the code you've changed that is relevant.